# Customizing the popup menu for displaying it's contents on the top of it's button Click?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, popup, popupmenu

I have created multiple buttons in my main activity, on click of each button a toast message would be displayed and on Long-click of each button, a popup-menu would be displayed.

As normal popup-menu displays the contents in drop-down format, but I want the popup menu contents to be displayed on Top of the button once the button is Long pressed. I have used menu.XML file to store the items for the popup menu.

Here is the **CODE**:

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v,Gravity.TOP);
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, popup.getMenu());

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn1:
                popup.show();
                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                popup.show();
                break;
            case R.id.btn3:
                popup.show();
                break;
            case R.id.btn4:
                popup.show();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have gone through many sites but most of them all are customized only by adding icons to the popup menu.
So Please, do let me know some of the ways to find the solution to it.
Thank you

Comment: Share screen shot .

Comment: I dont have permission to post the picture. It is displaying that I should have atleast 10 reputations to upload a image.
Shall i replace with the entire code.